# Application to save copies of reduced resolution photos on iPhone?

Tags: ios, photos

I am looking for an application that will save a copy of a photo on my camera at a smaller resolution. Can't find anything...thanks!

Comment: So you basically want all your photos to be resized and old versions removed?

Comment: Old versions of photos are acceptable to keep. Looking for something that will take the huge file size that Camera.app produces into something more manageable to upload. My end product here is a form that technicians will upload ~15 images to from the field. Obviously, you can't have 1.5-2.0mb images like that.

Comment: Take a look at my answer below. I'm certain that it is exactly what you are looking for, only... **FREE**. That might change your mind.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding whether you are looking for an iOS *camera* app, or an iOS image manipulation app (that reduces file size smoothly and easily)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used "MultiLoader" to do something similar (ie, upload 15-20 pictures for a document); but, it is only effective if you have a WiFi connection.  It creates a mini web server on the iPhone, zips all the pictures together at full or 1/2 or 1/4 resolution, and lets you connect to download them.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wifi-photo-multiloader/id448314967

Answer (score 2):

Try this: [Reduce - Batch Resize Images and Photos for iPhone & iPad](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/reduce/id580474806?l=de&ls=1&mt=8).

However, if you just want to reduce the photo uploading traffic, the iOS built-in Photo.app allows you to share the photos with size-reduced version.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [ImageOtim](http://imageoptim.com/) with some success.  Having said that it does not resize or reduce the resolution, it just compresses the images better, which might be enough for you or not -- in general I find that having better compressed larger images is easier *for me* than having not compressed small low res images.

Answer (score 0):

I have used an app called [**Resize Photo**](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/resize-photo/id426754772?mt=8) from the App Store.

**It's Free, and that made up all the difference for me!**

When using it, you may even save in batch with all the photos the same resolution. This was a phone-saver when I found myself with over 600 photos and only 16 GB.

Hope this helps.

Note: I am not in any way affiliated with the developer of this application, and am only stating my personal favorite application for resizing photos.

Answer (score 0):

Not free - Photoshop

you can do all of this quickly by doing it once while recording your actions, and exporting your actions as a droplet. A Droplet is essentially a self contained program that you drag image(s) to and it runs on them all.

Actions I'd suggest: Resize, Save For Web, Save As, Close Window, Do Not Save.

I've done this in the past for hundreds of images at a time when converting them for web display- essentially you're doing the same thing, but with some personalized tweaks for your phone.

If you have Photoshop, give it a try... if not, don't buy it just for this one feature!